# Javascript array to xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a JavaScript code as:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);
```

Now i want to re-write it in xml. This is my attempt:

```
        <title>Bar Chart - Company Performance</title>

        <dataHeadings index=0>

            <dataHeading index=0>Year</dataHeading>

            <dataHeading index=1>Sales</dataHeading>

            <dataHeading index=2>Expenses</dataHeading>

        </dataHeadings>.......so on
```

Is this right? I approached it as a 5x3 matrix but is it a 5x3 or more like 5x1 matrix? i feel like im doing it wrong. Any guidance would be of great help in this.

Comment: what attempt you're talking about? you need guidance towards what?

Comment: Guidance in terms of approach. Is this a 5x3 matrix or more like 5X1 matrix? @Sunny

Comment: To save re-inventing the wheel, there are a few lightweight JSON-XML libraries out there. I've not tried but you might want to take a look at http://neocotic.com/jsonx/.

Comment: @NeilCresswell : This is just a homework. I have been given a google chart code from developers page and asked to recreate the same thing using xml+xslt. I'm working on xml but can't seem to figure out if this array used in google a 5X1 or a 5x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looking at a structure like the following:

```
<performance>
    <annual year="value" sales="value" expenses="value" />
    <annual year="value" sales="value" expenses="value" />
    <annual year="value" sales="value" expenses="value" />
</performance>
```

Seeing as your year, sales and expenses are just values, you won't need a structure like this:

```
<performance>
    <annual>
        <year>value</year>
        <sales>value</sales>
        <expenses>value</expenses>
    </annual>
    <annual>
        <year>value</year>
        <sales>value</sales>
        <expenses>value</expenses>
    </annual>
</performance>
```

By the way, I think attributes must be in double quotes. e.g. index="1", not index=1.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

- XSL stands for EXtensible Stylesheet Language
- XSLT stands for XSL Transformations

both of these are ways of dealing with XML ... if you are attempting to parse the javascript array with XSLT, I am not sure you are going to have much luck.

However, if you are simply trying to figure out how to make the data usable with XSLT to the best of my knowledge it would be something like:

```
<Objects>
   <Object>
      <Year>2004</Year>
      <Sales>1000</Sales>
      <Expenses>400</Expenses>
   </Object>
   <Object>
      <Year>2005</Year>
      <Sales>1170</Sales>
      <Expenses>460</Expenses>
   </Object>
   <Object>
      <Year>2006</Year>
      <Sales>660</Sales>
      <Expenses>1120</Expenses>
   </Object>
   <Object>
      <Year>2007</Year>
      <Sales>1030</Sales>
      <Expenses>540</Expenses>
   </Object>
</Objects>
```